# MS Graph and Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

**Problem**: How to authenticate in MS Graph using Azure AAD access token.

**Current flow**:

My web app has AAD configured with "Log in with AAD"
[image]

If I log into AAD my demo app is showing and if I go to https://******.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
then I get the access_token.
[image]

**What I tried**:
So I tried a couple of things and this was the last, I copied the access_token as code and tried to send it, didn't work.
[image]

I'm searching for a solution to silently use the already logged-in user and call MS Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you have used the wrong `code`. Don't try to send the access token as a code, you should request an [authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) in your browser.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

In addition, `redirect_uri` is also a required parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the already logged in user you need follow the below steps for access:

1. Make sure you have enable the allow access token for the register app as below

[image]

2. Write code to acquire access token for the for the logged in user [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)
3. Now you can pass this token in other successive call to get the result.

Comment: did that and the output is as above

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the token, your grant_type should be client_credentials

[image: Using Postman to get a token]